Wallet Adapter (Standard) doesn't work on the iOS device
When I click Connect button, it identifies the wallets on Windows, Mac and Android but shows an empty list on the iOS devices:

Here's the code:
import {ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { FC, ReactNode } from "react";
import { useDaoMeta } from "./dao-provider";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const WalletModalProviderDynamic = dynamic(
    async () =>
      (await import("@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui")).WalletModalProvider,
    { ssr: false }
);

.....
....
return (
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={[]} autoConnect={true}>
                <WalletModalProviderDynamic>
                    {children}
                </WalletModalProviderDynamic>
            </WalletProvider>
        </

Do I need to include the individual adapters for the wallets for it to work on iOS?

I don't know about iOS but no, at this point in time all the major wallets support wallet standard and you no longer need to include the wallet-app specific wallet adapters.

Unfortunately most wallets can't be autodetected by iOS. On Windows/Mac they're injected into the page by a browser extension, and on Android they can use Mobile Wallet Adapter (MWA), which is included with wallet-adapter. MWA doesn't work on iOS.
Some options here:

If you're in a wallet's in-app browser, it'll show up because it'll inject itself like a browser extension
If a wallet includes a Safari extension then it can inject itself that way, and will show up in the list
If you explicitly include the deprecated Phantom or Solflare adapters, these will show up on iOS, and will redirect you to the same URL in their in-app browser


Thank you Callum. It was helpful.

How could I "include the deprecated Phantom or Solflare adapters"?

@cbeltrangomez you just add them to the wallets array. There's an example here: https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md#setup - you'd import and include eg PhantomWalletAdapter and SolflareWalletAdapter
